# C# Tuple - How to search for questions based on input from text box

Tags: c#, sql, tuples

I am creating a test where the radio buttons populate based on the test that the user needs to take.

The test is created by an admin in a table. We currently have a Favorite Color table already set in place but I am looking to future-proof our code to allow another test to be selectable. Below is my code but it was done quickly and thus has the Favorite Color table hardcoded in the SQL statement.

I am also using TUPLE to set the questions in a Binary pair. This allows the user to choose between 2 options. See below.

```
//Loads the Test data from the DB and organizes the data into Tuple Binary Pairs
    private void TestF_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        tempTable = new DataTable();
        tempTable.Columns.Add("Item1");
        tempTable.Columns.Add("Item2");
        tempTable.Columns.Add("Value");
        var tkey = new DataColumn[] { tempTable.Columns[0], tempTable.Columns[1] };
        tempTable.PrimaryKey = tkey;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT item_name FROM TEST_ITEMS I JOIN TESTS T ON I.test_id = T.test_id WHERE test_name = 'Favorite Colors'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        total = dt.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < total - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = total; j > i + 1; j--)
            {
                list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(), dt.Rows[j - 1].ItemArray[0].ToString()));
            }
        }

        // Get the items from the DB for test X (id = 1)
        // Randomize pairings
        // Present list[0].Item1
        // Author Nils Updated 5/8
        radioButton1.Text = list[0].Item1;
        radioButton2.Text = list[0].Item2;
        radioButton3.Text = "Undecided";
        location++;
        total = list.Count;
    }
```

Is there a way that I can have the user input the name of their test in a text box which can then update the SQL statement based on their input?

I have the textBox1 as my pre-established text box with a button to select once the input has been entered, however, all of my iterations result in radioButton1.Text = list[0].Item1; throwing an exception error 
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc0Sk.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextBox to input test name

```
string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["key"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT item_name FROM TEST_ITEMS I JOIN TESTS T ON I.test_id = T.test_id WHERE test_name = @testName", sqlConn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("testName", TextBox1.Text);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }

        // use dt as you did
    }
}
```

For the exception, I guess that `SELECT` didn't retrieve anything, use debug mode to check if `dt` filled with data as you expected.

By the way, where is `con` defined?

Comment: I had con defined under my partial class as a variable

Comment: public partial class TestF : Form
    {

        private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["productionConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        private List<Tuple<string, string>> list;
        private int location = 0;
        private int total = 0;
        private DataTable tempTable;
        private int sessionid;

Answer (score 0):

You can always have something like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT item_name FROM TEST_ITEMS I JOIN TESTS T ON I.test_id = T.test_id WHERE test_name = '{0}'", txtTestName.Text), con);
```

Where txtTestName is tahe TextBox that user will fill with Test Name. From UX perspective - this isnt a good approach.

- What if User doesn't know the Test Names?
- What if User makes Typo in Test Name?

Better Idea would be to have a Search or at least a DropDown (Combobox) where you pre-populate all available tests. That way user has a list of choices to pick from.

Comment: Upvote for suggesting a combo box but downvote for using String.Format which can have the same result as string concatenation.

Comment: @Mary - True - You can use string Concatenation. But then String.Format is cleaner & extensible (String interpolation is even better).

Comment: No, I am saying don't use either String.Format or string concatenation because of SQL injection can cause data loss.

Comment: Cant help much as OP has picked ADO.NET.

Comment: Huh? ADO.net provides command parameters to avoid string concatenation and potential data loss.

Comment: Isn't that several lines of code to do something quite trivial? Using EntityFramework (all OOP & not Sql execute) you get traditional SQL Injection safety without even knowing anything about it.

Comment: Good conversation! Not trivial if you are not using EF. I have not yet found a use for EF so I am not familiar. It is a layer on top of ADO.net so is a tad bit slower. I will sign off now. Thanks.

Comment: ADO.NET was part of the requirements, plus we plan on using MVC formatting later on.

Comment: I am going to try the other approach as well